# Is this quicksort algorithm from Grokking algorithm book correct?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I saw in some other articles that quicksort should be an in place algorithm, so is this implementation correct ?. Here the author is creating new arrays on each recursion step.

```
    function quickSort(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr
    } else {
        let pivotIdx = getRandom(arr.length)
        let pivot = arr[pivotIdx]
        let [leftArr, rightArr] = partition(pivotIdx, arr)
        
        return [...(quickSort(leftArr)) , ...[pivot] , ...(quickSort(rightArr))]
    }
}

function getRandom(maxInt) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxInt)
}

function partition(pivotIdx, arr) {
    let leftArr = []
    let rightArr = []
    let pivot = arr[pivotIdx];

    for (let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        if (i === pivotIdx) continue;

        if (pivot > arr[i]) {
            leftArr.push(arr[i])
        } else {
            rightArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }

    return [leftArr, rightArr]
}

quicksort([44,1,2,3])
```

Comment: Please reproducibly identify the source of the code presented, if not the origin.

Comment: This may sort, but you are correct that it’s not QuickSort proper.

Comment: how will i identify the source of the code?, i dont understand, not a native english speaker 
@greybeard

Comment: `how will i identify the source of the code?` What has been the original you were typing this in from, or copying from&pasting above? Tell it in a way that users here can check above rendition to be faithful. (What I remembered of above book was a disagreeable rendition in Python. A quick web search didn't suggest otherwise: Same problem you identified in your question.) Please see [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: There is a difference between asking "is this quick sort?", "is this an inplace algorithm?" and "is this a correct sorting algorithm?". What are you asking?

Comment: There is no correct or not correct. Depending on your definition of what "quicksort" is, this code is or isn't quicksort. I expect most experienced programmers to call this quicksort, but also identify that it's not a good practical implementation (both because it's not in-place, but also because it is quadratic when there's lots of repeated elements).

Comment: I would say that it is not a correctly implemented version of Quicksort simply because it does not display the characteristics that we identify with Quicksort.  Specifically, if you copy the arrays like then this it will *not* have average time complexity of `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung what will be the complexity then